# Eclipse debug can't find fields

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm using the Eclipse debugger and can't inspect/watch field values or results of field.method() calls.  I've encountered the problem in both Juno and now in Indigo.  At first I could resolve the issue by wiping out my **.metadata** and rebuilding, but now the problem occurs even with a fresh build.

A specific error: I create a Deflater object `deflater = new Deflater();`,
set some input `deflater.setInput(buffer, 0, bufferPosition);`,
then try to inspect functionality by highlighting a section of code `deflater.needsInput()`
and doing a **right-click->Inspect**.  The error reads: **"Cannot find the field deflater for the object apps.TestCore$Tests (id=27)"**.

The error only occurs when the field belongs to an inner class (In this case "Tests"); when the variable is local or the class is not an inner class, everything seems to be working.  Hovering over the variable "deflater" shows the contents drill-down just like it should.  Highlighting "deflater" and doing an Inspect gives the error, and using the Expressions view to inspect the variable/call methods on the variable gives the same error.

Please help; this is making my debugging life very difficult, as I have to use `println()` for anything more complex than a hover inspection can provide.

This is not remote debugging - just local to my system.

Comment: I get a similar problem trying to inspect on other classes.  For example, I have an "Integers" class which contains various utilities to do with ints.  Inspecting an "Integers" method yields the error "Integers cannot be resolved", despite the code working fine when it executes.